# How to run a set of TWEANN benchmarks in Erlang correctly?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I've been reading Gene I Sher's *Handbook to neuroevolution through Erlang* and trying to replicate all the experiments described there.
And it all worked, until I came to [chapter 19](https://github.com/CorticalComputer/Book_NeuroevolutionThroughErlang/tree/master/Ch_19), which read

> Having set everything up, we execute the benchmark for every noted experimental setup, and run it to completion. To do this, we simply modify the constraints used in our `benchmarker` module, and then execute **`benchmarker:start(Experiment_Name)`**, for every of our experimental setups.

There are 14 experiments altogether, named:

> 1. [SlidingWindow5]
> 2. [SlidingWindow10]
> 3. [SlidingWindow20]
>  4. [SlidingWindow50]
> 5. [SlidingWindow100]

and

> 1. [ChartPlane5X10]
> 2. [ChartPlane5X20]
> 3. [ChartPlane10X10]
> 4. [ChartPlane10X20]
> 5. [ChartPlane20X10]
> 6. [ChartPlane20X20]
> 7. [ChartPlane50X10]
> 8. [ChartPlane50X20]
> 9. [ChartPlane100x10]

Just starting a polis and running `benchmarker:start(SlidingWindow5).` in an erlang shell results in `* 1: variable 'SlidingWindow5' is unbound`.

I'm probably being obtuse and not doing something obvious, but I really wish to understand which arguments to pass to the `benchmarker:start()`.

**Reading the source code didn't help so far.**

I think that reading the whole book is not necessary to figure out how to make this particular piece of code work.

Answer (score 0):

All right. I needed to use an all-lowercase name: `benchmarker:start(slidingwindow5).`.
This answer is correct, but inconclusive; it gives the solution but does not explain why the solution is as it is from an Erlang perspective. Please don't upvote it until it does.

Comment: Did you even bother to take quick [Getting Started with Erlang Sequential Programming](http://erlang.org/doc/getting_started/seq_prog.html) intro to the language?

Comment: No. I did try reading and following this tutorial (http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content)

Comment: Well then try read [Invariable Variables](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#invariable-variables) and [Atoms](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/starting-out-for-real#atoms) again carefully. Especially pay attention to the first paragraph of Atoms.

Comment: Thanks, I"ll do that, among other things I'm thinkig of trying.