# Erlang benchmarker has problems reading files

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

This question relates to [the previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36030579/the-corect-way-to-run-a-benchmarker-in-erlang/36033872#36033872).
I'm running code cloned from [the official repo of the book](https://github.com/CorticalComputer/Book_NeuroevolutionThroughErlang/tree/master/Ch_19)
 When I run 
`benchmarker:start(slidingwindow5).`, I  get the following errors:

> 4> benchmarker:start(slidingwindow50). true Dimensions:4,
>   Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none Dimensions:4,
>   Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none Dimensions:4,
>   Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none Dimensions:4,
>   Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none Dimensions:4,
>   Plasticity:none Dimensions:4, Plasticity:none
>
> Specie_Id:6.858114617542796e-10 Morphology:forex_trader
>
> ******** Population monitor started with parameters:{state,benchmark,test,[],
>                                                        [],undefined,undefined,
>                                                        undefined,[],0,0,0,0,0,
>                                                        undefined,undefined,
>                                                        undefined,undefined,
>                                                        undefined,undefined,0.5,
>                                                        10,10,mathema,inf,10000,
>                                                        inf,<0.274.0>,false} Initial Tot Evaluations:0
>
> Started
>   Started 
>   Started 
>   Started
>   Started 
>   Started
>   Started
>
> 5> 
>   =ERROR REPORT==== 16-Mar-2016::14:11:34 === Error in process <0.287.0> with exit value:
>   {badarg,[{ets,last,['EURUSD15'],[]},{fx,init_state,5,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,375}]},{fx,sim,3,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,284}]}]}
>
> =ERROR REPORT==== 16-Mar-2016::14:11:34 === Error in process <0.288.0> with exit value:
>   {badarg,[{ets,last,['EURUSD15'],[]},{fx,init_state,5,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,375}]},{fx,sim,3,[{file,"fx.erl"},{line,284}]}]}Started Started Started

As far as understand it, the benchmarker can't find and use a table. Why is that happening, and how might I fix that?

**Update**: Renaming `EURUSD15` leads to error when running `polis:start().`:

> Mnesia(nonode@nohost): Data may be missing.

The `badarg` error stil occurs and is reported.

**Update**: digging into the source code, particularly into `fx.erl`, has lead me to believe that for some reason the .txt file called `EURUSD15` is not properly read from disk and so it's not converted into a table and can't be used by ets and the rest of the code.

What's wrong with file reading in `fx.erl`, and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 1):

[`ets:last`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#last-1) expects the table name as the only argument. However, in your code it's called with 'EURUSD15'. Is this the table name? Has the table been created? Please remember that when the table is created the process that created the table owns it. If that process dies then the table is deleted. You would need to debug your code according to the call stack from your error:

```
function fx:init_state/5 in file "fx.erl" line 375
called from
function fx:sim/3 in file "fx.erl" line 284
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that the issue is with the table. There is a folder called `fx_tables`, and it contains EURUSD, EURUSD.csv, EURUSD.txt and other files.
As I understand it, the table is present before the process is started and isn't deleted when it dies.

Comment: Look at the edit to figure out the folder structure of the whole project.

Comment: The table is either the atom representing the table name or the table id, see: http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#type-tab The table must have been created with `ets:new/2` before it could be accessed with `ets:last`, see: http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#new-2 The table isn't in a file, it's in the memory, so I am not sure what you mean by a folder called 'fx_tables'. Run `ets:i().` in Erlang shell, it will print out all tables created in ETS. Your table 'EURUSD15' must be on that list.

Comment: I thought that it goes like this: i run the code in erlang shell, the file (let's say the .csv one) from `fx_tables` is read and converted into a table erlang and ets specifically can use. Seems that I've been thinking something wrong.
`ets:i().` show a lot of tables (including the `experiment` table, which is important), but none named EURUSD or anything close.
Also, I suspect we should go to chat with such lengthy comments.

Comment: It's possible that the code that tries to read the table from disk doesn't work correctly or wasn't run so the data hasn't been copied from the .csv file to ETS. Maybe the examples in your chapter build on some code from previous chapters and the authors assume that the tables have already been loaded?

Comment: It's possible, but I think it's unlikely; I assume that whatever code is necessary for the whole thing to work is present.
As for .csv not being read for some reason, that seems more probable. I'm trying to figure out that reason.

Comment: Ok, `grep -r txt` and actual looking found that `fx.erl` deals with a `.txt`. I suppose that the .txt is meant to be read and converted into a table, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Update: `txt` is used ny `insert_ForexRaw(URL,Flag)` in `fx.erl`. The `URL` line above that is commented out in the original code. Uncommenting it and recompiling leads to error `illegal macro call'?'?''`

Comment: Another Update: recompiling everythig with `make:all([load]).` if the URL line is uncommented still leads to `illegal macro call`, but now the error is `Error in process <0.178.0> with exit value: {undef, [{fx,sim,[0.168.0],[]}]}`.

Comment: It means that the code tried to call `fx:sim/1` with the argument '0.168.0' but that function couldn't be found (either because the module 'fx' isn't loaded or because it doesn't contain the `sim` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106484/discussion-between-chiffa-and-amiramix).